# Python function works but has the wrong order

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

I am to write a function tourlength(tour, locations) that returns the total distance as a float of the given tour, i.e. the sum of the distances between the locations in the tour. For example the tour ("ngv", "fed square", "myhotel") has a total distance of 4.0

My Code:

```
import math

def distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):                                                    
    return math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2) 


def tourlength(tour, locations):
    DBP = []
    tour_list = [i for i in locations if i[0] in tour]
    coordinate = [i[1:] for i in tour_list]
    x_coordinate = [i[0] for i in coordinate]
    y_coordinate = [i[1] for i in coordinate]
    a = 0
    b = 1
    j = 0
    while j <= (len(tour_list)-2):
      distances = distance(x_coordinate[a], y_coordinate[a], x_coordinate[b], y_coordinate[b])
      DBP.append(distances)
      a += 1
      b += 1
      j += 1
    return sum(DBP)
```

Let's say I have my function defined as:

```
tourlength(["ngv", "fed square", "myhotel"], [("ngv", 4, 0), ("town hall", 4, 4),("myhotel",  2, 2), ("parliament", 8, 5.5), ("fed square",  4, 2)]))
```

The value returned is 4. However, my function returns the value 4.82842712474619 which is the value for the tour list `["ngv", "myhotel", "fed square"]`

I understand that my code does work, but fails to do so in the right order which I assume is due to this part: `tour_list = [i for i in locations if i[0] in tour]` but I am unsure as to adjusting it without importing other built in python functions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is just a sum of the distance from each point to point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tour_list is based on the order on locations and not based on the tours. This is better implemented using a dict.

```
import math

def distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):                                                    
    return math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2) 


def tourlength(tour, locations):
    DBP = []
    coordinates = {}
    for item in locations:
      coordinates[item[0]] = item[1:]
    j = 0
    while j <= (len(tour)-2):
      dest_1 = tour[j]
      dest_2 = tour[j + 1]
      distances = distance(coordinates[dest_1][0], coordinates[dest_1][1], coordinates[dest_2][0], coordinates[dest_2][1])
      DBP.append(distances)
      j += 1
    return sum(DBP)
```

Comment: hmmm I tried going through this but it failed one of the 3 hidden inputs to the function. However, it was able to return correct values for the questions. Thank you btw (it took me forever to find out how to define a dictionary key to tuples but now i get it)!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You iterate through locations, so tours are in order as in locations list. I advice you to turn locations into dictionary looking like `{"ngv": (4,0), ..}` ad change line `tour_list = [i for i in locations if i[0] in tour]` into

```
tour_list = [i for i in tour if i in locations.keys()]
```

But you can make your code much better. Dictionary here is very useful